# Magnolia 6.0 get current node in endpoint

Tags: magnolia

i have here a magnolia 6.0 running which uses ftl and need to find out the requested node to build a navigation and mark the current node as active.

I iterate over the pages and the subitems to get each navigation entry. but i didn't get the current node.

Example:

- my-website

  - page 1
  - sub page 1-1
  - sub page 1-2
  - page 2
  - sub page 2-1
  - sub page 2-2

the api calls to magnolia looks like the following:

`my-website/page-1/sub-page-1-2.json`

So i need to know `sub-page-1-2` is the current in the ftl templates.

I found a similiar questions, but this does not work for me:
[FreeMarker - Get Current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207429/freemarker-get-current-url)

So i tried the following:

- use `cmsfn.parent(content, "mgnl:page")` but with this i get the current page-module but not the current sub page.
- also use `cmsfn.decode(item)` but this gets me just the url to the item

Is there a way to get the asked node in the ftl template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get the requested node (content) or more information regarding the context.

Please have a look at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Rendering+context+objects

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: thank you, that was a good hint. now i use the context object and fetch the requested uri `ctx.getRequest().getRequestURI()`